# Getting value error for INT when posting DataFrame values to psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to insert a data to `postgresql` from a `dataframe` like this

```py
df["code"] = df["code"].astype(int)
insert_sql = '''
            INSERT INTO cs_houmon_ (code, name, city, add, phone)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
            ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT code DO NOTHING;
            '''
try:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(insert_sql, (df.code.to_list(), df.name.to_list(), df.city.to_list(), df.add.to_list(), df.phone.to_list()))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()

except Exception as e:
        log(str(e))
```

But getting this error code

```
code is of type integer but expression is of type integer[]
LINE 3: VALUES (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1...
```

My `sql` table was created like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE cs_houmon_ (code integer, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says what's the problem - the program expects integer and you pass list of integers there.

It's because `execute` is used to insert single row and as second parameter you should have single tuple of lenght 5.
If you want to insert many parameters, use [executemany](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/insert/) and pass list of tuples

```
cur.executemany(insert_sql, list(zip(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5))
```